# How to XOR two binary numbers having different length?

Tags: numbers, xor

I have two binary numbers x= 11010 and y= 11001000111110. Is this good method to XOR these numbers:

**Pad the shorter one on "x" the left with zeros, then XOR them**

x = 000000000**11010**

y = 110010001111110

z = x **XOR** y

Comment: Only humans shorten the value by dropping any leading values. The computer always sees `x` as `00000000011010`.

Comment: Why don't you just repeat X by multiple times to XOR the entire length of Y?

Comment: @chepner do you mean that no need to put zeros, and the computer will put zeros depend on the length of longer number??

Comment: There zeroes are already there; computers only deal with fixed-length numbers. It's just that humans will contract leading zeroes, just like "twenty" is written as 20, not (say) 000000020.

Comment: @chepner sorry I could not understand, if I have x= 11010 and y= 11001000111110, how the computer know the number of zeros ? and how it XOR x with y? could you please give me an example?
And what do you mean by: "computers only deal with fixed-length numbers"

Answer (score 1):

Think about XOR like this e**X**clusive**OR**.
Here is the table of XOR:
  [image]

So you're doing this for those numbers but **bit with bit**.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @chapner in the comment, you don't need to pad the shorter nunber with 0s.

You can just do x **XOR** y and you're good.

**Longer read:**

For a better understanding, consider this:
The computer understands only binary, so they only understand 0s and 1s. But, they specifically focus on 1s. Any bit of data that has 0, or does not have anything is always 0 for it.
(meaning, the computer only takes 1s as 1s, everything else is 0 for it.)

So, when you say 1 to computer, it takes it as 1.

XOR works by matching two numbers bit by bit, so when you say 1 XOR 100, the computer tries to match it bit by bit, and because 1 has no preceding bits, the computer takes them each as 0s.
(Remember, it only takes 1 where there is 1, rest all is 0 for them.)

So it effectively does 001 **XOR** 100 and returns 101.

I hope I am clear enough.